# How do I save TF2 Demos?

Tags: team-fortress-2

And I don't mean the class. How do I create/save Demos in game? I want to get some so I can use them as needed. Also, can you please tell me where I find the files it creates?

I belive they can be converted to a video (Youtube acceptable) format (if not, please tell me).

Comment: Person who downvoted, can you please tell me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demos can be recorded via the `record [filename]` and `stop` commands (where `[filename]` is the real filename without extension, such as `record mydemo`).

I believe they are saved in the root TF2 directory although I'm not at a computer with TF2 on it to check.  On Windows, this defaults to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Team Fortress 2\tf\`.  The file will be `[filename].dem`.

There is also a client plugin named p-rec that can be set up to auto-record demos if the game matches certain criteria.  This is commonly used to record competitive matches by recording matches where mp_tournament is enabled.  The current working version of p-rec for Team Fortress 2 is [2.0.5](https://bitbucket.org/olegko/p-rec/downloads/PREC2.0.5.zip) (2.0.6 is broken).  Once installed, typing `prec_info` into the game console will tell you what the various options for it do.

And yes, it is possible to convert Demo files to videos.  Since the replay update, TF2 can [convert it directly to a .mov file](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Demo_Video_Creation#Export_to_MOV.2C_new_with_Replay_Update_for_Team_Fortress_2).

Comment: Just a quick mini-question, what all does it record? HUD, killfeed, what? I can't test it out ATM, and I don't think it is worthy of a full question.

Comment: @ShadowZ. It should record anything you see.  I want to say that includes your HUD, but its been a while since I've checked.  Incidentally, the Replay system is based on the Demo system, so the two should record the same things, it's just that the Replay system is taken from the server side, so you can do camera manipulation with it.

Comment: So I can use it on servers without replays?  Also, it would record my menu?

Comment: @ShadowZ. Demos are local to your computer. Well, at least in the terms of this discussion they are.  As for the menu question, I'm not sure.  One important thing I forgot to mention: Demos automatically stop when the map changes.